# How to split a string on substrings with set of characters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Is there a quite simple way to split a string on substrings with set of characters like without using Regexp ?

```
abcd..,,qqww..::ss       - input
.,:    - characters
abcd qqww ss   - substrings
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: yes of course you can do `myWeirdString.split("");`

Comment: of course I Know about split(). But It uses only one argument. The point is that I have to handle a lot of characters that split the string.

Comment: Why can't you use a regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace()` to pass in the values you don't want present in the output.

```
var str = 'abcd..,,qqww..::ss ';
var newStr = str.replace(/[.,:]/g,''); // if you want to replace them with spaces, change '' to ' '
alert(newStr) // results in abcdqqwwss
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kdqtpcq9/

Comment: thats still a regex, but yea prob the best way to do it!

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why you wouldn't use regex. I hate regex just as much as the next guy, but sometimes when it's easy to do, it really is the most elegant solution.